# Title on chart for gvisAnnotatedTimeLine function

Tags: r, title, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I am using the `gvisAnnotatedTimeLine` function from the `googleVis` package, and was wondering if there was a way of adding in a Title (not an annotation) into the output, as I can't see an argument for it in the function help file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In alot of cases I use html and css to label plots from googlevis.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with html or css, can you give me a quick example of the code in `R` needed to do that, as I'm not sure where I would go about starting to put in the html code so that the titles appear...thanks...furthermore...would this work if you have used `gvisMerge` to put together a bunch of `gvisAnnotatedTimeLine` graphs, and you wanted the title on each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should include a title to the chart. The input is either an HTML string or a shiny.tag.

```
addGvisATLTitle <- function(gvisATL,title)  {

if (!all(class(gvisATL) == c("gvis","list"))) {
  stop('ERROR in addGvisATLTitle: Incorrect type, expect gvisAnnotatedTimeLine.')
}
if (class(title) == "character") {
  gvisATL$html$chart['divChart'] <- paste(title,gvisATL$html$chart['divChart'],sep="")
} else if (class(title) == "shiny.tag") {
  gvisATL$html$chart['divChart'] <- paste(as.character(title)[1],gvisATL$html$chart['divChart'],sep="")
} else {
  stop('ERROR in addGvisATLTitle: Unknown title type.')
}
return(gvisATL)
}
```

you can test it out with

```
 a <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date(),val=20)
 b <- gvisAnnotatedTimeLine(a)
 plot(addTitle(b,"<h1> My chart </h1>"))
 plot(addTitle(b,h1("My chart")))
```

- I have updated it to work with gvisMerge